# How to connect the quickbook pos with the asp.net using SDK

Tags: asp.net, blazor, quickbooks, pos

I have to connect the quickbooks pos with the asp.net web apps.
And also how to connect the quick book pos with the .net using the sdk.
I have to use the quickbooks api with web apps.

Comment: I have to do a lot of things also, but SO is not the place to list them. Please post what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: i have to connect the quickbook pos with the .NET WebApps Using The SDK SO How I Can Access That i did not clearly Find

Answer (score 0):

You can use Official QuickBooks POS SDK for integration.
here is basic information https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbdesktop/docs/get-started/get-started-with-the-quickbooks-pos-sdk

Alternatively you can export the End of the Day Summary in CSV / EXCEL file and then import them via windows service to your asp.net web server.

Kindly share if you are facing any specific error in connecting with quickbooks POS. happy to help.!

Comment: Hello @chintan123 i don't have exactly idea that how i connect the POS SDK With .net 6 can you help me in that